# Verilog net to reg assignment

Tags: verilog

I have an input port from_LS(511:0). This is declared as wire in my module. I am assigning this to a set of 32 registers ilb(0:31), each of which are 1 nits long. I was trying to use the for loop to do this.

```
 integer i;
 genvar j;
 initial
  begin
    count1 = 0;
    count2=0;
    flush_ctrl=0;
    buffer_bit=0;
    a=(hmic_ctrl[1]) + (hmic_ctrl[2]*2) + (hmic_ctrl[3]*4);
    //assigning data from LS to ilb

        for (i=0;i<=31;i=i+1)
          ilb[i]=from_LS[511-(16*i) : 511-(16*(i-1))];

    ilb[0]= from_LS[511:496];
    ilb[1]= from_LS[495:480];
    ilb[2]= from_LS[479:464];
    ilb[3]= from_LS[463:448];
    ilb[4]= from_LS[447:432];
    ilb[5]= from_LS[431:416];
    ilb[6]= from_LS[415:400];
    ilb[7]= from_LS[399:384];
    ilb[8]= from_LS[383:368];
    ilb[9]= from_LS[367:352];
    ilb[10]= from_LS[351:336];
    ilb[11]= from_LS[335:320];
    ilb[12]= from_LS[319:304];
    ilb[13]= from_LS[303:288];
    ilb[14]= from_LS[287:272];
    ilb[15]= from_LS[271:256];
    ilb[16]= from_LS[255:240];
    ilb[17]= from_LS[239:224];
    ilb[18]= from_LS[223:208];
    ilb[19]= from_LS[207:192];
    ilb[20]= from_LS[191:176];
    ilb[21]= from_LS[175:160];
    ilb[22]= from_LS[159:144];
    ilb[23]= from_LS[143:128];
    ilb[24]= from_LS[127:112];
    ilb[25]= from_LS[111:96];
    ilb[26]= from_LS[95:80];
    ilb[27]= from_LS[79:64];
    ilb[28]= from_LS[63:48];
    ilb[29]= from_LS[47:32];
    ilb[30]= from_LS[31:16];
    ilb[31]= from_LS[15:0];
    pctr(
     .clk(clk),
     .reset(0),
     .offset(branch_ctrl[13:1]),
     .mux_select(branch_ctrl[0]),
     .pc1(pc)
   );
  end
```

I was getting the error that I should not use a variable index. The error is :

```
# ** Error: C:/Modeltech_pe_edu_10.0/examples/COMP ARC/inst_line_buf.v(55): Range must be bounded by constant expressions.
```

So i wrote down the following:

```
ilb[0]= from_LS[511:496];
ilb[1]= from_LS[495:480];
ilb[2]= from_LS[479:464];
....
ilb[31]= from_LS[15:0];
```

But i guess there must be a better way to do this. Could anyone tell me how?

Comment: You've an instantiation in your `initial` block!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The orginal verilog doesnt allow this kind of expression as it wanted to assure that the width is always right (it is, but in earlier times compilers werent as good :-).

Verilog 2001 offers some solution with +: you can specify the width
e.g. `from_LS[ 511-(16*i) +:16 ]` in your loop.

EDIT: Another solution would be to put another loop inside, which copies 16 bits bit by bit.

Answer (score 1):

You should include more code (at least up to the `always` block containing that loop for the sensitivity list) and the exact error you're getting.

Does it work if you change `integer i` to `genvar i` and wrap the for in `generate` and `endgenerate`?